# Add data into table without auto increment

Tags: vba, excel

So i am trying to dynamically insert data into an Excel table from other closed workbooks.

**i got everything working just fine, except one small annoying thing.**

i have a formula as follows:

> ='H:\dev...[some book name.xlsm]Main'!C1

the formula above works fine. what i need is to insert this exact same formula into a table in the sheet for several rows.

it should look like that in one column:

> ='H:\dev...[some book name.xlsm]Main'!C1
>   ='H:\dev...[some book name.xlsm]Main'!C1
>   ='H:\dev...[some book name.xlsm]Main'!C1

what excel does, it automatically changes all the cell references to be incremental, like this:

> ='H:\dev...[some book name.xlsm]Main'!**C1**
>   ='H:\dev...[some book name.xlsm]Main'!**C2**
>   ='H:\dev...[some book name.xlsm]Main'!**C3**

i insert the the formulas as a string into an array,  and then paste it into the table using this code:

```
Set lstObj = Sheets(1).ListObjects(1)
Set rngLstObj = lstObj.Range
With rngLstObj.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngLstObj.Rows.Count - 1,rngLstObj.Columns.Count)
    .Formula = RevList  
End With
```

in the code above, `RevList` is a 2 dimentional array.

i tried setting it to `.Formula`, `.Value`, in both cases excel changes the cell references to be incremental.

i tried disabling calculation

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).EnableCalculation = False
```

still same.

how do i stop this behavior from VBA side?

Comment: Have you tried to use `offset(1,0).copy` instead of `resize`? That should copy your formula instead of filling it down.

Comment: @MátéJuhász im not quite sure how copying the destination range will help me with pasting the formulas into it... i think you have misunderstood my question.

Comment: Copy works similar as resize but doesn't change the formula. You can specify the destination range too: `rngLstObj.Offset(1, 0).copy rngLstObj.rows(2,rngLstObj.Columns.Count)`

Comment: @MátéJuhász i need to paste the data from the 2 dimentional array `RevList` into the destination range. the offset and resize methods are simply used here to select the table's body without the headers, thats all. its the `.Formula = RevList` part that handles the data insertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was resizing the destination range wrong, instead of:

```
With rngLstObj.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngLstObj.Rows.Count - 1,rngLstObj.Columns.Count)
    .Formula = RevList  
End With
```

i should have resized the range according to the array dimensions:

```
rngLstObj.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(RevList), _
UBound(Application.Transpose(RevList))) = RevList
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start with

```
='H:\dev...[some book name.xlsm]Main'!$C$1
```

it will force the absolute reference wherever it is copied.

The added dollar signs prevent the range from changing.